# How to create a custom template for this custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I've created this custom post type.

```
/* custom post - traveller posts */ 
add_action( 'init', 'traveller' );
function traveller() {
  register_post_type( 'traveller',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Traveller_Posts' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Traveller_Post' )
      ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'capability_type' => array("Traveller_Post", "Traveller_Posts"),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

That creates a post type 'Traveller_posts'

Now I have to create a template for these 'Traveller_post'types.

- So I created 'single-traveller.php' - Not working.
- Then I created 'single-traveller_post.php' - also not working
- Then I tried 'single-traveller_posts.php' - no luck again.

I put all these files into my child theme directory.

Why I am unable to get it works?
What can I do to get it works?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but don't name your function the same as your cpt. Change your function name, flush your permalink twice (just a double measure to make sure your permalink has been changed) and test again

Answer (score 0):

Create a File named archive-{yourposttype}.php and  Then start tweaking from there. You can style this archive file to your heart’s desire. A very basic template would look like this:

```
<?php
get_header();
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile; endif;
get_footer();
?>
```